# Can multiple Zend Form elements share a single Error decorator?

Tags: php, zend-framework

By default, error message decorators render under elements. How can I prepend just one error message decorator to my form that all the elements use to display their errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK no, but you can create your own FormError decorator, that would do just that! Assign it to the form and then receive the elements using `getElements()` and then get errors for each element to display. Actually I think it's a great idea and it inspires me to that for my own form class (now i use view helper for that). But make sure you still display error message near the field for useability reasons.

Comment: This sounds perfect, thank you! But, would it be too much trouble to ask for some sample code?

Comment: It's actually a lot of writing to do :) So, sry :) Check out manual page about custom decorators or this screencast: http://www.zendcasts.com/creating-custom-zend_form-decorators/2010/02/ to see how to implement custom decorator.

Comment: I understand, thank you for the link! When I finish it I'll post it to my blog or something

Comment: And don't forget to backlink here. Stackoverflow is top google result for 90% or my recent problems. It might give your blog a traffic boost :D